# How to display a popup message with infomation from record save

Tags: popup-window

< Hello every bodyi am new in salesforce and i want create VF with popup message,when i created record with descrption i want that popup message imadiatly when i enter to customer.

after that if want to see this message again i can click on the button page for see this popup message again.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, please show your work, what you have tried to so far?

Comment: please see [ask] for getting the most from the community